# EJB Module cannot find interface from dependency

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm having trouble with starting a Java EE application.

For starters, I have a maven module (let's call it A), with couple of interfaces, some of them marked as @Remote.

I have a module (named B), which has a provided dependency on A. This module is using Spring 5, I set up more-or-less fine for injecting the beans implementing interfaces from A.

I have an EJB module (C), which depends on A, implementing the interfaces in it.

I'd like to deploy C on a local WildFly server, for testing and running on a local environment, but I keep getting errors, saying that *No class def found for* the interfaces in A. I run the Spring 5 core on this module as well, to make use of some spring functionalities.

C is packed as ejb, A is default.

What do I have to do get this working? I feel like I completely misunderstand some key concepts here. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What are your deployment artefacts, and which of them contain A, B and/or C?

Comment: these are all separate ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide the interfaces (and all needed classes) within the EJB JARs, when deploying the EJB JARs directly. If you need additional libraries, you might need an EAR or a WAR deployment. So you are able to provide library JARs, too.

Use the matching maven (war or ear) plugin to provide the artifacts.

Comment: So it means that I have to make a module D, which is packaged as an EAR make a dependency on both A and C and deploy that?

Comment: This is the most reasonable approach if you want to deploy an enterprise application on an application server. You are using the defined dependencies and scopes from your build. Be aware of configuration files (e.g. application server specific deployment descriptors) and application server provided dependencies might change if your production runtime environment differs from the testing runtime environment.